# Python sanitizing html from a string

Tags: python, parsing

Is there a way to escape all quotes and double quotes in a string?

For example if I have a string like this:

`Hi my name is 'Shelby"`

Is there a way to preprocess this to escape that string?

EDIT:

Maybe that wasn't the best approach to the problem. So here's what I'm actually trying to do, I have a tool that analyzes `swf` files, (namely `swftools` -> `swfdump`) But sometimes, some malicious `swf` files will contain `html` tags, and I'm outputting these results to a page. So is there a way to sanitize these `html` tags in python?

Sample of string:

```
 (    3 bytes) action: Push Lookup16:443 ("title_txt")
 (    0 bytes) action: GetMember
 (    6 bytes) action: Push Lookup16:444 ("htmlText") Lookup16:445 ("Please check your Log In info.")
 (    0 bytes) action: SetMember
 (   14 bytes) action: Push int:2 int:1 register:1 Lookup:30 ("login_mc")
```

For the part that says `Please check your log info` it's supposed to say: `font color = '#ff0000'`

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: What are you escaping from? HTML? URL's? Javascript? SQL? Something else?

Comment: I'm just trying to process some data, and if I by chance feed in a string that contains both double and single quotes, python cuts it then and there. So I was curious if there's a way to escape the quotes, not manually.

Comment: Perhaps this is because I'm not familiar with `swf` files, but what you have in your updated post is one *single* string, and you are trying to locate and print out all of the strings enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: @Levon I'm just trying to find a way to sanitize html in such way that I can print the raw html code to the page instead of letting the browser interpret the html as html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just going for HTML sanitizing, you can try this:

This is probably the easiest approach if you want to add more escape types:

```
def escape(htmlstring):
    escapes = {'\"': '&quot;',
               '\'': '&#39;',
               '<': '&lt;',
               '>': '&gt;'}
    # This is done first to prevent escaping other escapes.
    htmlstring = htmlstring.replace('&', '&amp;')
    for seq, esc in escapes.iteritems():
        htmlstring = htmlstring.replace(seq, esc)
    return htmlstring
```

This replaces every instance of `&`, `'`, `"`, `<`, and `>` with their correct HTML escape codes.

More information on HTML escaping:

[Wikipedia HTML Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Character_and_entity_references)

[Every Escape imaginable](http://www.hybridelephant.com/computer/tutorial/spechar.html)

Happy Escaping!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a templating like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/), they will do that for you already. All text which is embedded into the page will be properly escaped unless you *explicitly* tell it not to. When building web-pages, it might anyway be a good idea to use a templating-engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the current approach is to use the [html module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape).

```
import html
html.escape('Hi my name is \'Shelby\"')
Out: 'Hi my name is &#x27;Shelby&quot;'
```